# Ubuntu 15.10 does not boot on Intel NUC6i3 with Samsung 950 Pro PCIe NVME SSD

Tags: grub2, uefi, intel-nuc, nvme

I tried to installed Ubuntu 15.10 on the NUC6i3 using a Samsung 950 Pro PCIe NVME SSD.
Booting USB drive in UEFI mode was possible and the system runs ok. Installation itself also without problem. After restart the NUC can't find a boot device.
Booting the USB drive again I looked up some details:
(1) Partitions seem to be ok on the /dev/nvme0n1
(2) EFI boot entries do NOT look ok, somehow destroid

Installing Ubuntu 15.04 on the other hand has been posible without problems. Everything but wifi works out of the box.

What excactly is the difference between 15.10 and 15.04 concerning GRUB, EFI and NVME?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the difference between 15.04 and 15.10 with respect to GRUB, EFI, and NVME, but I found a way to make 15.10 work on my NUC 5i5RYK with Samsung NVMe drive.

No BIOS configuration changes are necessary. I've seen some posts say that you need to change the EFI or Legacy boot settings by at least with my NUC that had no effect.

Here's two work arounds that I found - perhaps the will help you.

1) Use the GUI program Boot Repair - This requires you to boot to a working system using a USB stick or CD using Kubuntu or other LiveCD style installer. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair for information. The default or "Recommended Repair" doesn't work, but I selected the "Advanced Options" and uncheck "SecureBoot" but keep all other default options then follow the instructions, the system correctly boots to the newly installed OS.

2) Install Ubuntu 15.04 first, then upgrade to 15.10. I found that if I install 15.04, run all updates:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then run

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

then 15.10 will successfully boot.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.nvmexpress.org/resources/linux-driver-information/), NVMe support didn't land into the linux kernel until version 3.3, and according to [distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu), 15.04 is still using kernel version 3.19. It looks like you will need to upgrade to 15.10 which uses the 4.2 kernel.

However, in order to boot from the drive, the BIOS also needs to support NVMe, and I'm not sure about NVMe support in the latest Intel BIOS for the NUC.

I've been thinking about buying this exact equipment combo, so I'm hoping you try this and report back.

Comment: I believe 3.19 is newer than 3.3.

Comment: yeah, 3.19 is newer than 3.3. Linux kernel version numbers are a bit weird like that.